# Unable to build war using maven with Z/OS dependency

Tags: java, maven, zos

I am trying to build a war where i am using the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>jzos</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

While building the war with clean install i am getting following error

```
Failed to execute goal on project AbcService: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.abc:AbcWar:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
Failed to collect dependencies at com.ibm:jzos:jar:2.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.ibm:jzos:jar:2.4:
Could not transfer artifact com.ibm:jzos:pom:2.4 from/to IBM repository `enter code here`(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.jaxrs):
Access denied to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.jaxrs/com/ibm/jzos/2.4/jzos-2.4.pom.
Error code 403, Forbidden -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: Please post your full pom and settings.xml (suitably redacted of course)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've got some oddness in your setup, most likely due to a `<server>` defined in your `settings.xml` that your Maven installation is using.

I'm guessing that `enter code here` is just an error when writing the StackOverflow entry. So ignoring that, I think you've got a `<server>` defined named 'IBM repository', with its root URL to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.jaxrs/ that doesn't look right, as that address is an individual artifact on a server that shows what artifacts exist on Maven Central, not a Maven artifact repository.

That artifact (`com.ibm:jzos:2.4`) is not available on public repositories like Maven Central. So I think what you probably want to be doing is setting your server to be some company-internal artifact repository like Nexus or Artifactory, where that artifact has been uploaded.

Check through your `settings.xml` files for where this misconfiguration might have occurred. If you're not sure which files are being used, run Maven with the `-X` option to get debug logging and search for `Reading global settings` and `Reading user settings`.